# ndarray that updates its data on demand

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to have a system, where I have a "Data class" that has some arrays and a "Selection class" that has the same array names whose data are just a mere view on a subset of the arrays from the Data class. which ones should be determined by the instance of the selection class. If one changes something in the instance of the Selection class it should get mapped back to the corresponding Data class and to make things really difficult, not only should the arrays from the selection class be real ndarrays (so al the methods should work), they should also be only views on teh original data or only be created on demand.

The scaffold I have created so far is

```
import numpy as np

class DataObj():
    def __init__( self, Data_dict ):
        self.arrays = [ n for n,d in Data_dict.iteritems() ]
        for n,d in Data_dict.iteritems():
            setattr( self, n, d )

class Darray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, SelObj, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array[ SelObj.selA, SelObj.selB ]).view(cls)
        obj.SelObj = SelObj
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return  

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return super(Darray, self).__getitem__(index)      


class SelObj():
    def __init__(self, DataObj, selA, selB):
        self.selA = selA
        self.selB = selB
        self.DataObj = DataObj

        for n in DataObj.arrays:
            Darr = Darray( getattr( self.DataObj, n), self )
            setattr( self, n, Darr )

### creating some objects
DObj  = DataObj({ "X":ones((10,20)),
                  "Y":zeros((10,20)),
                  "Z":arange(10*20).reshape(10,20) })

SObj1 = SelObj( DObj, array([1,3,4]), slice(None,None,2) )
SObj2 = SelObj( DObj, array([4,5,7]), slice(None,2,None) )
SObj3 = SelObj( DObj, array([1,3,4]), slice(None)        )
```

This works, but now If a do

```
SObj1.X = 10
```

it looses the connection and just has a 10 instead of the original array. Even when I do something that actually makes sense like

```
SObj1.X[0,0] = 10.
```

this will not appear in the DObj ( because with `input_array[ SelObj.selA, SelObj.selB ]` I created a copy of the array ). Ans now every SObj will have it's own data which will eventually clog up memory.

I know what I want will not be easy but I would still like to do it. I was also looking into properties and making every Darray a property of SObj; doing the slicing on demand whenever the property is called. However then things like

```
SObj1.X[0,0] = 10.
```

will not work anymore, since the property already slices and an additional slice is not mapped back anymore.

I would be very grateful for any hints that would point towards a solution of this structure.

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an expression like

```
SObj1.X = 10
```

to change values of some distant sources, you should override `__setattr__` method in your `SelObj` class. Like this:

```
class SelObj():
    def __init__(self, DataObj, selA, selB):
        self.selA = selA
        self.selB = selB
        self.DataObj = DataObj

        for n in DataObj.arrays:
            Darr = Darray( getattr( self.DataObj, n), self )
            setattr( self, n, Darr )

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        setattr(self.DataObj, name, value) # updates the source of the data
        super(SelObj, self).__setattr__(name, value) # updates the representation
```